# JSTL import / load xml document from string variable

Tags: xml, jsp, jstl

In a JSP page, using JSTL I can load an xml file, from xml file path or url to jstl variable as following:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<c:import url="my.xml" var="xmldocument"/>
```

Now, how do I do the exactly same thing if my xml file is in a String variable instead of the file system?

Say I have

```
<%
String strXmlDoc = "<books><book><name>Padam History</name><author>ZARA</author><price>100</price></book></books>";
%>
```

how do I import that to jstl var "xmldocument"?

Thanks.

Comment: Found it! Simply passing the variable to JSTL seems work fine. 
hah! didn't think it would!

    <%
    pageContext.setAttribute("xmldocument", strXmlDoc);
    %>

Comment: You shouldn't mix scriptlets with taglibs/EL. The one is oldschool way of writing JSPs and the other is modern way of writing JSPs (well, modern.. it's done since almost a decade already.. imagine how *oldschool* those scriptlets are!). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<c:set var="xmldocument"><books><book><name>Padam History</name><author>ZARA</author><price>100</price></book></books></c:set>
```